# What is the subject in the following sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, syntactic-analysis

What is the subject in the following sentence?

> Who hit the ball through Mr. Brown's window?

How can we tell what the subject is in a sentence like this in terms of the grammar?

Comment: What comes to mind is . . . "Who's on first?'

Comment: It can only be "who", since it is in the usual subject position, before the verb. Compare:~ "**Ed** hit the ball ...", ~ "**Who** hit the ball ...?",  where it is clear that if "Ed" is the subject, then so must "who" be.

Comment: @Xanne "Who" is the subject in all meanings though :)